# Collector or ForEach for adding multiple elements

Tags: java, functional-programming

I want to fill a List by merging two Streams, perform some operations on them and finally grab all elements and store them. Two approaches came to my mind:

*Collector*:

```
myList.addAll(Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)
    .flatMap(foo -> someMethod(foo).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

*ForEach*:

```
Stream.concat(stream1, stream2)
    .flatMap(foo -> someMethod(foo ).stream())
    .forEach(myList::add);
```

Is there a difference in performance that expells one solution from using?

Does the first, collector using method, create a temporary List that is immediately consumed and discarded by `List#addAll`?

**EDIT**
This Question is meant to generate answers that somehow explain the functionally and/or performance. I don't want to start an debate about what way "looks better" etc. That would be highly opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the streams API but I would expect `collect` to be a better choice just because it has more information.

The `foreach` approach cannot know in advance the size of the streams, allocate the right size to `myList`, etc.

The `collect` approach in theory might have access to more information that it can use to make optimizations. As a general rule of thumb where possible I prefer to use methods that perform the whole operation in one go rather than iterating over them. In the worst case scenario the operation will just do the iteration internally.

It's the same way as in old school collection processing you would favour `list.addAll(x)` rather than iterating over `x` and adding each element. `addAll` has the potential to do optimizations that you do not know about and in the worst case will be the same performance as the manual iteration.

Comment: @Holger Yes, that was my meaning. see "allocate the right size to `myList`"

Comment: Oh, I have mistaken “foreach approach” for “forEach method”, because the sentence is formulated like a typical discussion of a method.